# Como publicar uma aplicação com dependência de processos junto?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

Existe alguma forma de publicar um console aplication com dependência de outros consoles ?

Tenho hoje uma tela de Windowns Form que é minha tela de login, nela seleciono qual console application deve ser executado passando o local físico de onde o executável esta, só que se eu publicar o Windows Form os consoles não são publicados juntos.

Minha chamada dos executáveis.

```
var jsonParametros = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parametros)));
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(pathFile);
info.Arguments = string.Join(" ", funcional, senha, robo.IdRobo, robo.VersaoAssemble, funcionalFila, esteiras, racf);
info.Arguments = jsonParametros;
processo.StartInfo = info;

processo.Start();
```

Tem como gerar um único executável com todos os outros processos juntos ?

Comment: que instalador você está utilizando?

Comment: eu gero um através do visual Studio.

Comment: eles não estão dentro da mesma solution?

Comment: Quando você fala em gerar um único executável com todos os processos juntos, você se refere a criar um instalador? Se a questão é só "publicar" todos juntos e eles estão na mesma solution, uma altertativa é mudar o output path dos projetos no perfil de release, ou ainda criar um perfil de "deploy"

Comment: Sim , eles estão na mesma solution, teria como monta um passo a passo de como seria o deploy ?